# wp_nav_menu: If Nav menu First li empty Then add Value

Tags: php, wordpress

I Want to replace First wp_nav_menu li value using string replace , Or if First value Empty, i'm trying with this code

```
function mytheme_walk_nav_menu_items($output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    if ( $args['theme_location'] === 'sub-footer-menu' ) {
      $current_year = '&copy ' . date("Y").' Mindjet';
        $output = str_replace( '©2016 Corel', $current_year, $output );
    }
    return $output;
}
  add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'mytheme_walk_nav_menu_items', 10, 4 );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct but the line:

```
$output = str_replace( '©2016 Corel', $current_year, $output );
```

will work only if '©2016 Corel' is found into your $output string. Please print the $output variable to check whether the "©2016 Corel" is there inside or not. If there is little bit a single spacing then also str_replce will not work.